# Hide top bar when user scrolls list view upside and then make it visible again as user scrolls down

Tags: android, android-actionbar, scrollview

I want to hide top bar when user scrolls list view up and then make it visible again as soon as user scrolls down. It is same as the Google Plus bottom menu appears while scrolling down and it goes as soon as we scroll up. I have tried on scroll which is giving me first visible item. But it's not helping me as it requires a list view item to be scrolled fully to get previous first visible item. please anyone help me I am so badly stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to add a View (a layout with a textView or ImageView) beneath your ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" />
```

The weights are important to show both components.
After that, implements the listView's onScrollListener.

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //get the showed item num, and if its equal to total, you can hide the view
        //get a reference to your viewid
        viewid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }
});
```

When it reaches the last line, setVisibility(View.GONE) for the bottom View.
If you want to show this View again, when user scrolls up, modify the code. Of course, you can use aother layout, a textView, or something else.

**UPDATE**

I played with the a layout a little bit, and there is an other solution for your layout file, where the bottom View is overlaying the listView, so the removing of this textView is smooth.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052332/listview-indicate-more-scrollable-itmes) for more details